# How to apply a low-pass or high-pass filter to an array in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing

Is there an easy way to apply a low-pass or high-pass filter to an array in MATLAB? I'm a bit overwhelmed by MATLAB's power (or the complexity of mathematics?) and need an easy function or some guidance as I couldn't figure it out from the documentation or searching the web.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Look at the [`filter`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/filter.html) function.

If you just need a 1-pole low-pass filter, it's

```
xfilt = filter(a, [1 a-1], x);
```

where a = T/τ, T = the time between samples, and τ (tau) is the filter time constant.

Here's the corresponding high-pass filter:

```
xfilt = filter([1-a a-1],[1 a-1], x);
```

If you need to design a filter, and have a license for the Signal Processing Toolbox, there's [a bunch of functions](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/signal/f9-131178.html), look at [fvtool](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/signal/fvtool.html) and [fdatool](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/signal/fdatool.html).

Answer (score 4):

You can design a lowpass Butterworth filter in runtime, using `butter()` function, and then apply that to the signal.

```
fc = 300; % Cut off frequency
fs = 1000; % Sampling rate

[b,a] = butter(6,fc/(fs/2)); % Butterworth filter of order 6
x = filter(b,a,signal); % Will be the filtered signal
```

Highpass and bandpass filters are also possible with this method. See https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/butter.html

Comment: Warning.  This requires the Signal Processing Toolbox.