# Filter Function with Low Pass Filter

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, lowpass-filter

I've been searching all over but I can't seem to understand the following example provided on here back in 2009.

I'm trying to implement a simple low pass filter to a set of data in Matlab and this is the following example I was referred to here on SO. [Link to example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783633/matlab-apply-a-low-pass-or-high-pass-filter-to-an-array)

```
xfilt = filter(a, [1 a-1], x);
```

where `a = T/τ`, `T` = the time between samples, and `τ` (tau) is the filter time constant.

Now the coefficients are what are giving me the most trouble. Based off of the first order Laplace transfer function being the following:

`(1/Ts) / (1 + (1/Ts))` where `(1/Ts) = a`

It would be great to know how the denominator coefficients were found for the function above.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [`filter`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html) documentation, the first argument is *Numerator coefficients of rational transfer function*, let's call them `[b0 b1 b2 ...]` and the second argument is *Denominator coefficients of rational transfer function*, let's call them `[a0 a1 a2]`.

Since you want a single-pole low pass filter, the time domain equation is:

> ```
> A0*y(n) = B0*x(n) - A1*y(n-1);
> ```

You can simplify the above equation making `a0 = 1;`, `b0 = B0/A0` and `a1 = A1/A0;`

> ```
> y(n) = b0*x(n) - a1*y(n-1);
> ```

For stability reasons and if you want no change of gain, you will fix `b0 - a1 = 1;`

> ```
> y(n) = b0*x(n) - (b0-1)*y(n-1);
> ```

The equivalent transfer function is

> ```
> H(z) = b0 / (1 + (b0-1)*z^-1);
> ```

So the numerator coefficient is `b0` and the denominator coefficients are `1` and `b0-1`. Hence the writing of `xfilt = filter(b0, [1 b0-1], x);`

If `fc` is the frequency cut and `Fs` the frequency sample, `b0 = 2*pi*fc/Fs`.